Error of unmet dependencies and dpkg set-selection error
i am using ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I am using kernal version 6.8.0-39-generic I am running 64bit x86 architecture.
when i try to run: sudo apt upgade , i got this erroruser@omkar:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wpasupplicant : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installed
Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but it is not installed
Depends: libnl-3-200 (>= 3.2.21) but it is not installed
Depends: libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7) but it is not installed
Depends: libnl-route-3-200 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libpcsclite1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libreadline8t64 (>= 6.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libssl3t64 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installed
Depends: adduser but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

for this error i tried to run:sudo apt --fix-broken install. and i got new error.
user@omkar:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  adduser apt apt-utils ca-certificates dbus dbus-bin dbus-daemon
  dbus-session-bus-common dbus-system-bus-common debconf debconf-i18n dpkg
  gcc-14-base gpgv libacl1 libapparmor1 libapt-pkg6.0t64 libassuan0
  libaudit-common libaudit1 libbz2-1.0 libc6 libcap-ng0 libcap2 libcrypt1
  libdb5.3t64 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libffi8 libgcc-s1 libgcrypt20 libgmp10
  libgnutls30t64 libgpg-error-l10n libgpg-error0 libhogweed6t64 libidn2-0
  liblocale-gettext-perl liblz4-1 liblzma5 libmd0 libnettle8t64 libnl-3-200
  libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnpth0t64 libp11-kit0 libpam-modules
  libpam-modules-bin libpam0g libpcre2-8-0 libpcsclite1 libreadline8t64
  libseccomp2 libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage2 libsepol2 libssl3t64
  libstdc++6 libsystemd0 libtasn1-6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libtext-wrapi18n-perl libtinfo6 libudev1 libunistring5 libxxhash0 libzstd1
  openssl passwd perl-base readline-common sensible-utils tar ubuntu-keyring
  zlib1g
Suggested packages:
  perl cron quota ecryptfs-utils apt-doc aptitude | synaptic | wajig dpkg-dev
  gnupg | gnupg2 | gnupg1 powermgmt-base default-dbus-session-bus
  | dbus-session-bus debconf-doc debconf-kde-helper debconf-utils libgtk3-perl
  libnet-ldap-perl libterm-readline-gnu-perl whiptail | dialog debsig-verify
  gnupg glibc-doc locales libnss-nis libnss-nisplus rng-tools gnutls-bin
  libpam-doc pcscd readline-doc bzip2 ncompress xz-utils tar-scripts tar-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adduser apt apt-utils ca-certificates dbus dbus-bin dbus-daemon
  dbus-session-bus-common dbus-system-bus-common debconf debconf-i18n dpkg
  gcc-14-base gpgv libacl1 libapparmor1 libapt-pkg6.0t64 libassuan0
  libaudit-common libaudit1 libbz2-1.0 libc6 libcap-ng0 libcap2 libcrypt1
  libdb5.3t64 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libffi8 libgcc-s1 libgcrypt20 libgmp10
  libgnutls30t64 libgpg-error-l10n libgpg-error0 libhogweed6t64 libidn2-0
  liblocale-gettext-perl liblz4-1 liblzma5 libmd0 libnettle8t64 libnl-3-200
  libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnpth0t64 libp11-kit0 libpam-modules
  libpam-modules-bin libpam0g libpcre2-8-0 libpcsclite1 libreadline8t64
  libseccomp2 libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage2 libsepol2 libssl3t64
  libstdc++6 libsystemd0 libtasn1-6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libtext-wrapi18n-perl libtinfo6 libudev1 libunistring5 libxxhash0 libzstd1
  openssl passwd perl-base readline-common sensible-utils tar ubuntu-keyring
  zlib1g
0 upgraded, 78 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/22.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 77.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: 25600
Extracting templates from packages: 38%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: 25600
Extracting templates from packages: 76%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: 25600
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (100)
E: Couldn't clean the currently selected dpkg states

in this error i thought that first i have to install debconf.Then i tried to check first debconf is installed:
user@omkar:~$ apt policy debconf
debconf:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.86ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.5.86ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
so i run this code : sudo apt-get install debconf. and again i got error of unmet dependencies.
user@omkar:~$ sudo apt-get install debconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wpasupplicant : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libnl-3-200 (>= 3.2.21) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libnl-route-3-200 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpcsclite1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libreadline8t64 (>= 6.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libssl3t64 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

and also i tried to run sudo apt purge wpasupplicant. THE RESULT!
user@omkar:~$ sudo apt purge wpasupplicant
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wpasupplicant*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 3,853 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (100)
E: Couldn't clean the currently selected dpkg states


There are so many issues, I'd suggest a fresh installation of Ubuntu, using the latest ISO: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview . Save any data, remove all partitions. and reinstall. You might choose Extended selection and Proprietary software, to avoid having to install them later.

I think there's some missing context here. Could you try backing up your wpasupplicant config files, sudo apt purge wpasupplicant and reinstalling it? purge WILL delete your config, but there's no reason a common package would have issues with dependancies.

as you said to reinstall but while reinstalling it i must need a usb installer but i am not able to install it also. Getting above errors.

Is there any way to fix this error
